# Carriage return not working on linux if console window is too small for text

Tags: python, linux, stdout, carriage-return

I struggled for days when trying to dynamically update the printed output using carriage return. On Windows everything worked fine, but on Linux new lines are printed all the time. I tested all the different solutions provided on stackoverflow but none of them worked. Finally I found out that it is all about the linux terminal window size! See the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys

def printing():
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write('\r%.8g                                     %s'%(np.random.rand(), 'test             '))
        sys.stdout.flush()

printing()
```

On Windows (Spyder) you get the expected result, namely that only one line is printed and updated.
On Linux it seems to depend on the console window size, because if the window is large enough that the whole line fits in, then this line is updated correctly. However, if I make the window so small that the text is partly in a new line, then the script makes this:

```
0.81887604                                  test   
0.93397997                                  test    
0.67231912                                  test    
0.83398159                                  test    
0.26675238                                  test    
0.64693328                                  test    
0.12057606                                  test    
0.17320486                                  test    
0.42479957                                  test    
0.12575117                                  test    
0.18562281                                  test
```

How can I prevent this? In my actual script I cannot predetermine what the length of the text will be, so I do not know the required console window size.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I suggest to redirect the sys.stdout to a file at linux. For example `python xxx.py > result.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately this is no workaround for me as the program's intent is too display these values continuously.